# Web Scraping issue on page load with infinite scroll

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

i have to scrape an Ecommerce website which loads 45 Products on first page and subsequently loads additional 45 Products upon scrolling to end of the page.

I am using Python a Selenium Web Driver for scraping this page.

The Ajax seems to replace the container upon every subsequent reload and thus am not able to extract all the data after all the products are loaded.

Attaching the code for your ref. please guide me on how to scrape all the products

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas
from numpy import long

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
html=driver.get("https://www.ajio.com/women-jackets-coats/c/830316012")
assert 'Ajio' in driver.title
content = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item')
totalitems=long(driver.find_element_by_class_name('length').text.strip(' Items Found').replace(',','',10))

loop_count=int(((totalitems-len(content))/len(content)))

print(loop_count)

data=[]
row=['Brand','Description','Offer_Price','Original_Price','Discount']
data.append(row)

for i in range(1,loop_count):
    content = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('item') 
    print(i)
    print(len(content))

    for item in content:
        row=[]
        row.append(item.find_element_by_class_name('brand').text.strip())
        row.append(item.find_element_by_class_name('name').text.strip())
        row.append(item.find_element_by_class_name('price').text.strip().strip('Rs. '))
        try:
            row.append(item.find_element_by_class_name('orginal-price').text.strip('Rs. '))
        except NoSuchElementException as exception:
            row.append(item.find_element_by_class_name('price').text.strip('Rs. '))

        try:
            row.append(item.find_element_by_class_name('discount').text.strip())
        except NoSuchElementException as exception:
            row.append("No Discount")

        data.append(row)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight-850);")
    try:
        myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'loader')))
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Loading took too much time!")



df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv(r"C:\Ajio.csv", sep=',',index=False, header=False, mode='w')   #mode='a' for append
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem that you're having is an inconsistency in the data you're scraping based on subsequent reloads/scrolls.

One solution would be to store a data structure higher than the scope of this function that would record the items you've seen so far. As the page reloads/scrolls you can check if each item exists in the data structure already and if it doesn't add it to the structure until you can ensure that you've hit every possible item on the page.

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi, it seems the data is not available completely even if i scrape all items after full scroll in loop. i am ok even if i get duplicate records as i can then remove duplicates using Excel.

it seems the data is getting reloaded in the div

When i scroll down and just do a Ctrl+F on the web page for the first item, its not found. similarly when i scroll back up on top, i am not able to find the last item (Product) while i am on top of the page.

I am not a web developer and thus am not aware of what is this technology called. if someone can help identify the technology for right direction

Comment: Checked again, If i shut down my network / internet, and then if i scroll the page up or down, all the data which were downloaded earlier does appear on screen, which means that the data is somewhere in the page getting populated on the screen. or is it coming from the cache?


Still havent got any solution for this

Comment: I have managed to resolve the issue.
Instead of using Selenium here, i have used Requests to load the API which returns JSON and then JSON was read. That solved my purpose of web scrapping. Reading JSON was much faster than reading the website using Selenium 
I passed page no as parameter to the JSON API to load next page data.